# Does fetch support multiple file upload natively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, upload, fetch-api

### Summary

I am trying to set my `FormData` properly using javascript.

I need to be able to upload `jpg/png`, but I might need to upload some other file types `pdf/csv` in the future using fetch.

### Expected

I expect it to append the data to the form

### Error

[image]

### Working

This snippet is working fine:

```
const formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
formData.append("extraField", "This is some extra data, testing");

return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/upload/multi', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
});
```

[image]

### Not working

```
const formData = new FormData();
const input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
formData.append('files', input.files);
```

[image]

### Question

Does `fetch` support multiple file upload natively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is in the line`formData.append('files', input.files);`
Instead of that, you should upload each file running a loop with unique keys, like this

```
const fileList = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files;
    for(var i=0;i<fileList.length;i++) {
    formData.append('file'+i, fileList.item(i));    
}
```

I have created a simple error fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0mrcmbo/1/) with your code. You can check its' submitted post data here, where you can see that no file has been uploaded.

At the bottom of the page you can find

[image].

I have corrected the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0mrcmbo/2/) with the fix. You can check its'post data from the server, where it shows the details of the two files that I uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want **multiples** file, you can use this

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

var data = new FormData()
for (const file of input.files) {
  data.append('files',file,file.name)
}

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/upload/multi', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Genius!

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828061/3625228): I had the same problem, but with a PHP backend. The unique `formData` keys work, but I found that the classic HTML notation worked just fine and simply results in an array on the server.

```js
formData.append('file[]', data[i]);
```

I like that a lot better, since I can use the same methods to process this as with a classic `<input type="file" multiple />`.