# Send Multiple Files to PHP with Jquery and Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm building an HTML form using Jquery to send the data to a PHP backend. It is supposed to allow for multiple attachments, which are then sent via `fetch`. I'm receiving the `$_POST` fine, but `$_FILES` only contains the last file selected.

I know this is because the `multiple` attribute resets every time a new file picker window is opened, but I it to save each file as it is selected. To address this, I'm trying to capture each file in a JS array, appending the array to `FormData` before it posts to the server.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    // Add input files to array
    $('#inputId').on('change', function(e) {
        fileList.push(fileName[0]);
    });

    // Form submission
    $("#formId").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append(fileList);
        url = '../php/submit.php';
        fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: formData})
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(function(body){
                console.log(body);
            });
    });
});
```

```html
<form id="formId" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="ds-row ds-file-upload-container ds-mar-b-2">
    <div class="ds-col-xs-12 ds-col-md-6">
      <label for="inputId" class="ds-button">Choose a file
        <input type="file" class="ds-file-upload" name="upload[]" id="inputId" multiple="multiple">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As of now, the form is not submitting anything when the `submit` button is clicked. If I comment out the `#inputId` onchange event, it works, but of course, it doesn't have all the files included in the `FormData`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does fetch support multiple file upload natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738642/does-fetch-support-multiple-file-upload-natively)

Comment: Improper use of `FormDataInstance.append()`.

Comment: _“I know this is because the multiple attribute resets every time a new file picker window is opened”_ - what are you talking about here …? `formData = new FormData(this);` alone should be enough to send _all_ the files currently selected via the input field, it doesn’t need manual appending of anything.

Comment: @CBroe - That method didn't work for me. Every time I tried to add a second file to `upload[]`, it only retained the last file selected. The first file disappeared. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code for you and tested as well.

You have few issues with `formData` append. You are not doing any forEach for your file so so when you are sending the fetch request you formData only gets the last file.

To store multiple file you need to have an empty array which i have named as `filesToUpload`

This array will store all the file which you will select on change function.

Once the array contains all the files you want to upload. On form submit function you will loop through that `filesToUpload` array and append all its data to `formData` and send it via fetch request.

On the backend `PHP` side when you `var_dump($_POST)` OR `var_dump($_FILES)` you will see all these files there.

**Working fiddle Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/woft6grd/

In the demo when you go dev tools -> network you will see on form submit your request will have all the files you uploaded via input.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Add input files to array
  var filesToUpload = []

  //On Change loop through all file and push to array[]
  $('#inputId').on('change', function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      filesToUpload.push(this.files[i]);
    }
  });

  // Form submission
  $("#formId").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Store form Data
    var formData = new FormData()
    //Loop through array of file and append form Data
    for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
      var file = filesToUpload[i]
      formData.append("uploaded_files[]", file);
    }

    //Fetch Request
    url = '../php/submit.php';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
  })
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formId" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <div class="ds-row ds-file-upload-container ds-mar-b-2">
    <div class="ds-col-xs-12 ds-col-md-6">
      <label for="inputId" class="ds-button">Choose a file
        <input type="file" class="ds-file-upload" name="upload[]" id="inputId" multiple="multiple" required>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I have added comments to each code line as well to highlight as well.