# Upload multiple files/images, fetch, formData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, post, fetch

I want to upload images through `fetch()`. I used `formData` and succeeded to upload, but only one image at a time.

```
handleGetNewPictureDragDrop = data => {

        console.log(data);

        const formData = new FormData();

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            formData.append('filename', data[i]);
        }

        console.log(...formData);

        const name = this.props.nameCategory;

        fetch('http://api.../gallery/' + name, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(success => console.log(success))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

console.log(data):[image]

console.log(...formData):[image]

console.log(success): [image]

I take 3 images, create `formData`, there are 3 images but after POST-ing this `formData` I get uploaded only one.

Comment: Please refer to this to upload multiple files using fetch  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473250/7153915

Comment: thank you, finally I create a little change and it works:  `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            formData.append(data[i].name, data[i]);`
        }

Comment: Your welcome mirov, Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use unique key while appending multiple files to form data.

```
formData.append('file'+i, data[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the same 'name' to append for each image.
the Syntax should be

```
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

and that first one should be the field name, and if not unique, it overwrites.

try making it dynamic

```
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        formData.append(`filename_${i}`, data[i]);
    }
```

or probably something else (unique from your data) would be better, just don't pass the same name for each image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but with a PHP backend. The unique `formData` keys work, but I found that the classic HTML notation worked just fine and simply results in an array on the server.

```js
formData.append('file[]', data[i]);
```

I like that a lot better, since I can use the same methods to process this as with a classic `<input type="file" multiple />`.